# Headphone volume settings change after pressing play

Tags: headphones, iphone, sound-volume

Here's an annoying iPhone 6 interaction I have on a regular basis:

1. I plug my headphones into my iPhone.
2. I open Podcasts and browse for what I want to hear.
3. I use the volume buttons to set the headphone volume to a pleasant low setting.
4. I put the headphones in my ears.
5. I press play.
6. The headphone volume changes to 100% volume, and Marc Maron blasts holes in my ear drums before I can turn the volume down or pull the headphones out of my ears.

How can I set the volume *before* pressing play? Or at least how can I keep an app from resetting my headphone volume when playback starts?

Comment: Is this only happening for the Podcasts app (assuming you mean the one from Apple)? Is it only happening with one specific pair of headphones?

Comment: No, it happens for other apps too, like Spotify and YouTube. I use one set of headphones, but sometimes I will connect my phone to my car radio via the headphone jack.

Answer (score 1):

I share this problem--but my sense is that the headphone volume reverts to the last volume the headphones were on.  I have the volume loud in the car, but when I run I want it much lower--I have to either lower the volume before leaving the car or lower it before listening with phones.  Otherwise blasting ensues.  Wish there were another way.

Comment: I think the problem was related to my using the headphone jack to connect my phone to my car radio. I have since started using Bluetooth to connect my phone in my car and no longer have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this issue is caused by the following setting:

Set **Settings** >> **Music** >> **Sound Check** = OFF

For more information, here's Apple's description of the [Sound Check feature](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201724).

Comment: This is not the problem. I just checked and Sound Check is off. It's not a matter of volume leveling or anything like that. It's that the app (and other apps too, like Spotify and YouTube) will reset the headphone volume to some default when playback starts.

Answer (score -1):

back in 2006

http://www.dailytech.com/Man+Sues+Apple+Over+iPod+Hearing+Loss/article579.htm

In France, for example, all new iPods have limiting software inside the unit to govern the volume below 100 decibels -- the current models in the US can reach upwards of 125 decibels.

I believe this is the same for phones